# Clear entry text from ViewModel using RelayCommand

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, command, relaycommand

I would like to clear entry text from my ViewModel which is binded there. In the code below I tried it by using a RelayCommand, but it doesn't work.

What i want to accomplish: When clicking button named `AddQuestionToQuiz`, a function is executed by using Command on the button. The function `OnCreateQuizClick()`, located in my ViewModel, is triggerd and this function needs to clear my entry text, which i don't get for the moment.

I also tried to use a regular Command instead of using a RelayCommand, but also here it doesn't want to work.

**EDIT: UNDERNEATH CODE WORKS FINE - GOT UPDATED**
**Code is used to clear entry text when clicking on a button from your ViewModel, implementing INotifyPropertyChanged Interface**

**.xaml - code**

```
<Button x:Name="AddQuestionToQuiz" WidthRequest="200" Command="{Binding CreateQuizCommand}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Text="Add question to quiz"></Button>
```

**ViewModel - code**

```
internal class CreateQuizPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Quiz Name Input
    public String QuizNameInput { get; set; }

    private String quizQuestionInput = "";
    public String QuizQuestionInput 
    {
        get { return quizQuestionInput; }   
        set { quizQuestionInput = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    } 

    public RelayCommand CreateQuizCommand { get; set; }

    public CreateQuizPageViewModel()
    {
        CreateQuizCommand = new RelayCommand(OnCreateQuizClick);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void OnCreateQuizClick()
    {
        QuizQuestionInput = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: your VM does not implement `INotifityPropertyChaged` so the UI is not being notified of changes to the VM

Comment: I edited my code above by a working example (ViewModel is updated), Thanks @Jason. Also works by using a normal Command instead of a Relay Command

Comment: Instead of adding the working code to the question, please add it as "Your Answer" below. This makes it easier for anyone who sees this question to realize that it has been answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: VIEWMODEL UPDATED

.xaml - code

```
<Button x:Name="AddQuestionToQuiz" WidthRequest="200" Command="{Binding CreateQuizCommand}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Text="Add question to quiz"></Button>
```

ViewModel - code

```
internal class CreateQuizPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Quiz Name Input
    public String QuizNameInput { get; set; }

    private String quizQuestionInput = "";
    public String QuizQuestionInput 
    {
        get { return quizQuestionInput; }   
        set { quizQuestionInput = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    } 

    public RelayCommand CreateQuizCommand { get; set; }

    public CreateQuizPageViewModel()
    {
        CreateQuizCommand = new RelayCommand(OnCreateQuizClick);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void OnCreateQuizClick()
    {
        QuizQuestionInput = "";
    }
}
```